# separate rows based on timestamps

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

My dataset looks like this:

```
      main_id            time_stamp                        
          aaa            2019-05-29 08:16:05+05     
          aaa            2019-05-30 00:11:05+05     
          aaa            2020-05-30 09:15:07+05     
          bbb            2019-05-29 09:11:05+05
```

For each `main_id`, I want to:

a) sort the time_stamps in an ascending order

b) I want to create a new column `day`, which uses the time_stamp to derive a number that describes the business day.

Business days are defined like this:

Monday 05:00 - Tuesday 01:00 (1 Business Day i.e Monday)

Tuesday 05:00 - Wednesday 01:00 => (1 Business Day i.e Tuesday)

and so on...

The first and second rows with `main_id = aaa`are from the same business day since the second row is showing time before 1 am on the next day. So, this is the very first business day and the `day` column would have `1`.

However, in the third row, the timestamp is from another business day so we add `2` as the `day`.

The end result could look something like this:

```
      main_id        time_stamp                             day
          aaa            2019-05-29 08:16:05+05              1
          aaa            2019-05-30 00:11:05+05              1
          aaa            2020-05-30 09:15:07+05              2
          bbb            2019-05-29 09:11:05+05              1
```

Day 1 would be anywhere between the first 5:00 am - next day's 1 am. While day 2 would be the next possible business day (next 5 am - 1 am)

How can I achieve this?

```
df = df.sort_values('vehicle_id')
```

Comment: What should happen between 1 and 5 am?

Comment: nothing. I am assuming that there's no data between those time slots @mozway

Comment: Then a simple subtraction should work, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method would be to subtract 5 hours, then to group by sorted dates to get the group number:

```
df['time_stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_stamp'])
s = df['time_stamp'].sub(pd.Timedelta('5h'))
df['day'] = df.groupby(s.dt.date).ngroup().add(1)
```

*NB. you actually don't need to sort the values, `groupby` sorts the value by default.*

Variant to apply per "main_id":

```
df['day'] = (df.groupby('main_id')
               .apply(lambda d: d.groupby(s.dt.date).ngroup().add(1)).droplevel(0)
            )
```

Output:

```
  main_id                time_stamp  day
0     aaa 2019-05-29 08:16:05+05:00    1
1     aaa 2019-05-30 00:11:05+05:00    1
2     aaa 2020-05-30 09:15:07+05:00    2
3     bbb 2019-05-29 09:11:05+05:00    1
```

Comment: could you explain your code a bit? why are you subtracting 5?

Comment: To align your custom business day to a normal day by starting 5 hours earlier: 5->1 becomes 0->20 (you could actually subtract only 1 hour here).

Comment: Would be great if you could explain a bit more... also the ngroup() part. ALSO, with the current code, the timestamps are not sorted in an ascending order. How can I achieve that as well? Such that the items are still grouped by the ```main_id```s in all ```aaa```s are together and then all ```bbb```s are together. I have already sorted the main_ids before your code snippet as shown in the qs

Comment: Going offline now, I'll elaborate later

Comment: To sort the dates just use `df = df.sort_values(by=['main_id','time_stamp'])`

Comment: could you explain this part a bit more? ```df.groupby(s.dt.date).ngroup().add(1)```

Comment: Sure, for each group (here each date), get the group number (from 0 to n-1), and add 1 as you want your count to start by 1

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to sort the timestamps in ascending order, do this:

```py
#Let's say the dataframe is df
df['time_stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_stamp'])
df.sort_values(by='time_stamp')
```

2. For the business days one, I would do this:

```py
day1= #add the end of the first businesss date, like:  2019-05-30 01:00
df['day']=1
for i in df.index:
    df['day'].iloc[i]+=ceil(df['day'].iloc[i] - day1)
```

Comment: While sorting by timestamps, I also want to ensure that the grouping of main_id remains the same.

Comment: also, I wouldn't know what's the end of the first business day. will have to extract it from the df